# PHP curl multi memory issues

Tags: php, curl

Using multi exec curl in my application

```
$ch = array();
$mh = curl_multi_init();
for($i=0;$i<=1000;$i++){
    $ch[$i] = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_URL, '');
    curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);    
}
$running = 0;
do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
} while($running > 0);
$output = array();
for ($j = 0; $j < 1000; $j++) {
    $results = curl_multi_getcontent($ch[$j]);
    $resp = json_decode($results, true);
    array_push($output,$resp);
}
return $output;
```

This obv performs 1000 requests. The response is quite bigg / request and this gives me an out of memory issue.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: As always the solution to this is _not_ to collect all payload you receive from wherever and _then_ to start processing it. Instead you should process the results in a sequence: each payload you receive shoudl be processed right away so that you can free memory again before switching to the next iteration.

Comment: Is this possible when using multi exec?

Comment: How big do you expect it to get?  You can increase the `memory_limit` depending on how large each response is assuming you need `$output` all at once and not in pieces.

Comment: Each resp seems to be ~25KB  so around 30-35 Mb on occasions where the req are > 1000